# How to fix 'ERROR _HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE' in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got some error and I have no Idea what does It mean any ideas, please?
This is the error:
I have no idea what is going on because I never got the error like that before and I am using res.redirect same way as always. I found out that you should use res. render, but I want to be redirected to a page not to render the page...

---

```
> Sun, 10 Feb 2019 18:47:15 GMT express deprecated res.redirect(url,
> status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead at
> routes\placeorder.js:50:17 RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]:
> Invalid status code: [object Object]
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:208:11)
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:55:19)
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:55:19)
>     at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:199:8)
>     at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)
>     at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
>     at writetop (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\express-session\index.js:290:26)
>     at ServerResponse.end (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\express-session\index.js:351:16)
>     at ServerResponse.redirect (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:947:10)
>     at putOrderToDBAndRedirect (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\routes\placeorder.js:50:17)
> _http_server.js:208
>     throw new ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE(originalStatusCode);
>     ^
> 
> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code:
> [object Object]
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:208:11)
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:55:19)
>     at ServerResponse.writeHead (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:55:19)
>     at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:199:8)
>     at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:585:9)
>     at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:709:5)
>     at writeend (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\express-session\index.js:261:22)
>     at Immediate.ontouch (C:\Users\Petr\WebstormProjects\BakalarskaPrace\node_modules\express-session\index.js:348:11)
>     at processImmediate (timers.js:632:19)
> 
> Process finished with exit code 1


const putOrderToDBAndRedirect = async(res,userId,serviceObj,
                                      ordStart,ordEnd) =>{
    try{
        const result = await pool.query('SELECT id ' +
                                            'FROM orders ' +
                                            'WHERE ($1,$2) OVERLAPS (ord_start,ord_end)',
                                            [ordStart,ordEnd]);
        if(isOverlaping(result)){
            console.log('redirect to page with orders');
            res.redirect('/objednat')
        }else{
            await pool.query('INSERT INTO orders (ord_entered,ord_start,user_id,service_id,ord_end)' +
                                ' VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)',
                                [new Date(),ordStart,userId,serviceObj.id,ordEnd]);
            const resultArr = await pool.query('SELECT firstname,lastname,phonenumber ' +
                                            'FROM users ' +
                                            'WHERE ' +
                                            'id = $1',[userId]);

            console.log(resultArr.rows[0]);
            const obj = constructOrderObj(serviceObj,ordStart,resultArr.rows[0]);
            res.redirect('/objednano',{orderObj:obj});
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.error(err);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `res.redirect('/objednano',{orderObj:obj});` but that does not match [the function signature for `res.redirect()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect) which takes an optional status as the first argument and the path as the second argument (or the path as the first argument if there is only one argument, in which case status will default to `302`).

It's unclear to me what you're trying to do there, to be honest. But that line is the problem. It's treating the first argument as the status code, and `'/objednano'` is obviously an invalid HTTP status. So the error message is complaining that the HTTP status is invalid.

Comment: Hi thank you I am stupid now I noticed I should use res.render('/objednano',{orderObj:obj}). when I want to pass some objects for my .ejs view I have been working on that all day long I should probably take a break. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

If you use `res.redirect` to send the response to the client, it will have a status code of **302** (which basically is a redirect) means that the *the current data that you need is not available in the current location, but in another location as redirected*

If you are trying to get this resource from a frontend app or client (like using fetch or XMLHTTPresponse, then you might get such an error)

The best possible way is to explicitly tell `express` (or the `response` object) that you are trying to send a json response for **this request**